# Acceder a los elementos del Vector miembro de clase

Tags: c++

Buen día... no comprendo la forma de acceder a los miembros de los elementos de la clase curso. Es un puntero a la clase Estudiante. Pero al mostrar los datos de cada estudiante me marca el error:

`24 13  C:\Users\Luquin\Desktop\POO\Cursos\Curso.cpp    [Error] request for member 'mostrarDatos' in '* it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Estudiante**, std::vector<Estudiante*> >::operator->()', which is of pointer type 'Estudiante*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)`

```
//Archivo Estudiante.h
#ifndef ESTUDIANTE_H
#define ESTUDIANTE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Estudiante {
public:
    Estudiante(const string& nombre, int edad);
    void mostrarDatos();
private:
    string nombre;
    int edad;
};

#endif
```

```
//Archivo Estudiante.cpp
#include "Estudiante.h"
Estudiante::Estudiante(const string& nombre, int edad) : nombre(nombre), edad(edad) 
{

}
void Estudiante::mostrarDatos() 
{
   cout << "Nombre: " << nombre << ", Edad: " << edad << endl;
}
```

```
//archivo Curso.h
#ifndef CURSO_H
#define CURSO_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Estudiante.h"

using namespace std;
class Curso {
public:
    Curso(const string& nombre);
    void agregarEstudiante(Estudiante* estudiante);
    void mostrarEstudiantes() ;
private:
    string nombre;
    vector<Estudiante*> estudiantes;
};

#endif
```

```
//Archivo Curso.cpp
#include "Curso.h"
Curso::Curso(const string& nombre) : nombre(nombre) 
{

}



void Curso::agregarEstudiante(Estudiante* estudiante) 
{
    estudiantes.push_back(estudiante);
}

void Curso::mostrarEstudiantes() 
{
    cout << "Estudiantes en el curso " << nombre << ":" << endl;
  /*  for (const auto& estudiante : estudiantes) 
    {
        estudiante->mostrarDatos();
    }
    */
    
    for (vector<Estudiante*>::iterator it = estudiantes.begin(); it != estudiantes.end(); ++it) {
        it->mostrarDatos();
    }

/*  cout<<"Total de elementos: "<<estudiantes.size()<<endl;
    for( size_t i; i<estudiantes.size(); i++)
    {
        estudiantes[i]->mostrarDatos();
    }
    */
}
```

El primer for funciona, pero necesito usar el for tradicional, hasta donde investigue se supone que se utiliza el elemento iterator para ir recorriendo los elementos del vector estudiantes pero envia el error descrito arriba

El tercer for que hice no imprime nada. No marca error pero no muestra el contenido de las instancias estudiante1 y estudiante 2. aunque en el size si me dice que hay dos estudiantes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Curso.h"
#include "Estudiante.h"

using namespace std;
int main() {
    Estudiante estudiante1("Juan", 20);
    Estudiante estudiante2("Maria", 22);

    Curso curso("Programacion Orientada a Objetos");
    curso.agregarEstudiante(&estudiante1);
    curso.agregarEstudiante(&estudiante2);

    curso.mostrarEstudiantes();

    return 0;
}
```

Que estoy haciendo mal o que estoy pasando por alto?

entender el acceso a los miembros de las instancias de objetos en un vector

Answer (score 1):

En el caso del segundo for, `it` es un iterador. Para poder acceder a su contenido, tienes que usar `*it`. En consecuencia, el segundo for quedaría así:

```
    for (vector<Estudiante*>::iterator it = estudiantes.begin(); it != estudiantes.end(); ++it) {
        (*it)->mostrarDatos();
    }
```

En el caso del tercer for, simplemente falta setear la variable en cero en el for:

```
    for( size_t i=0; i<estudiantes.size(); i++)
    {
        estudiantes[i]->mostrarDatos();
    }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Que oso con el segundo for 